# Database Design to Search Multiple Colors

Tags: mysql, schema, database-schema

**Question: How can I search by up to five colors with this database design? If it's not possible, is there a better solution?**

This is a color search that I've built, and it works great for one color, but I am trying to allow someone to search up to 1-5 colors and ideally it would find media that have all or some of those colors.

The query input starts with a hex code, then is converted to RGB. I currently store up to 5 colors (might store up to 8 in the future).

```
CREATE TABLE `media_has_colors_unique_index` (
  `media_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `red` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `green` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `blue` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `percentage` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sequence` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`media_id`,`red`,`green`,`blue`),
  KEY `index_on_hex` (`hex`),
  KEY `index_on_percentage` (`percentage`),
  KEY `index_on_timestamp` (`sequence`),
  KEY `index_on_media_id` (`media_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here's an example of the query I'm running on a temp database with around a million records:

```
SELECT media_id, hex, percentage
FROM media_has_colors_unique_index
WHERE 
((red BETWEEN 41 AND 50) AND (green BETWEEN 166 AND 203) AND (blue BETWEEN 216 AND 264)) 
    AND 
((red BETWEEN 137 AND 168) AND (green BETWEEN 215 AND 262) AND (blue BETWEEN 223 AND 272))
GROUP BY media_id
HAVING percentage > 0.3
LIMIT 100;
```

The part of the query that reads `BETWEEN 41 AND 50` are dynamically created for each color channel in PHP by calculating a match threshold based on percentage: `MIN = ceil($rgb[0] * .9)` and `MAX = ceil($rgb[0] * 1.1)`. Essentially 10% in either direction—this allows for a range of color matches that are still visually similar to the original color search.

**Question: How can I search by up to five colors with this database design? If it's not possible, is there a better solution?**

Comment: You are not clear about what you want. What does "search by multiple colors" mean? Or "match with multiple colors"? Please read about MVCEs. Example input, query and desired output is helpful. Your example query returns media with a colour that is in the first 3-D range AND that is the second 3-D range. Not the media with a colour in the first range and the media with a colour in the second range. The latter are media with a colour that is in the first range OR that is in the second range. If you want those media then use OR instead of AND. (But it's not clear what you want.)

Comment: @philipxy hmm I'm not sure how I can make my question more clear... but it still is "How can I search by multiple colors with this database design, or if not this one, what is a database design I could use?" To me it's obvious that when searching you want matches, so "search by" or "match by" really is one in the same. But essentially I am trying to allow someone to search up to 1-5 colors and ideally it would find media that have all or some of those colors.

Comment: You finally said "find media that have all or some of those colors". (Although the "all" is redundant.) "Search" & "match" say you seek something but they do not express what the *criterion* is. Eg compare to "find media (that have *all* those colors)". It's not enough to write *some* things *consistent* with your understanding, you have to write a *specification* or *contract* that causes that understanding in the other person's mind. (And it turns out  that "color" means "3-D colour range".)

Answer (score 0):

> find media that have all or some of those colors

Your example query returns media with a colour that is in the first 3-D range AND that is the second 3-D range. Not the media with a colour in the first range and the media with a colour in the second range. The latter are media with a colour that is in the first range OR that is in the second range. If you want those media then use OR instead of AND.